# I am unable to fetch return value from a function in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In the code mentioned I am trying to get value of "text" which is inside the function . Outside of a function with one variable "A" but here I am not getting anything.Can anyone help me on this issue please

Also when I am writing print statement inside the function it is printing the value

enter code here

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
def callback(self):
    text = No_of_chances.get()
    return text
No_of_chances = Entry(window)
No_of_chances.place(x=50, y=300)
No_of_chances.bind('<Return>', callback)
A=text
print(A)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text` variable is not defined when you try to do `A=text` this is because the function `callback()` is only called when the enter button is pressed. Therefore `text` does not exist when you try to assign it to `A`

The callback function works perfectly fine, it gets the current string within the `Number_of_chances` Entry you have, and returns it.

That being said your question is very unclear, since you provide no context to what you want to do with the text you get from the `Entry` when you press enter, if you provide some context I or someone else might be able to help fix your problem better.

Here is a solution so then A will contain the value you want.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
text = ""

def callback(event):
    text = No_of_chances.get()
    print(text)
    return text

No_of_chances = Entry(window)
No_of_chances.place(x=50, y=300)
No_of_chances.bind('<Return>', callback)
A=text
print(A)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Mathew. 
Thanks for answering my question and yes I just want to get the value of the entry box and trying to print it for my further logic .I also tried your way but seems this is still not working

Comment: @KaranAgrawal where do you want to get the value of the entry box and what do you want to do with it? Because right now the way the code is written, A will not be updated when the entry box is filled and you press return.